# Need help creating a tiled background of a pink circle

Tags: css

I'm not a CSS pro, but I've gotten this far. Can anyone else shine some light on this code? I'm trying to create a background that has multiple pink circles as the background.

```
body {
background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, #ff72f7 40%, rgba(255,114,247,0) 40%) 100px 100px;
  background-color:white;
  background-size:250px 250px;
}
```

Comment: It seems that you have already created a background with multiple pink circles as the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use it:

```
<script>
document.body.setAttribute("style", "background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, #ff72f7 40%, rgba(255,114,247,0) 40%) 100px 100px; background-color:white; background-size:250px 250px;");
</script>
```

You can test it in the console of your browser.

Video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tqnSHhFPBnbV80bkFHRkMxeEE
HTML: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tqnSHhFPBnQVR0TlJaSWgxRzA
Another HTML: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tqnSHhFPBnckJsWnNNcEV0Q0E

Comment: This is the result - http://imgur.com/a/0H2K1 I'm looking for the pink circle tiled throughout the background without them moving.

Comment: Your screengrab is what I'm looking to execute - maybe a little tighter. If you look at the screengrab I attached above - that's what I see. Just two large circles.

Comment: I'm glad to help you! Please mark this answer as a solution.

Comment: Will do! One more question. What if I wanted to offset the circles like this? http://imgur.com/a/li9b1

Comment: [test-2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tqnSHhFPBnd2c2dUF2TWJkdGs) page | 
[test-3](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tqnSHhFPBnelg3SlJvMTBZSVk) page - more similar to the example. | [HTML colors](http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/hex-to-rgb/color-converter.php)

Comment: [test4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tqnSHhFPBnYmZoc2pyek91RHM) | page - another example.

Comment: Amazing - you've been such a big help. THanks much!!